# Google autocomplete UK only and without Country

Tags: javascript

I've seen a few similar postings to this but can't seem to incorporate anything into my site. I'm trying to "restrict" google map autocomplete to UK only, and also remove country from the complete address - for example if user searches London rather than input being London, United Kingdom, I'm trying to achieve just London only.

Here is my current script :

```js
                                jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                                    cs_fe_search_map();
                                    cs_load_location_ajax();
                                    if (jQuery("#fe_map0 #cs-map-location-fe-id").hasClass("gllpMap")) {
                                        var vals;
                                        cs_map_location_load('0');
                                        if (vals)
                                            cs_search_map(vals);
                                    }
                                });
                                function cs_fe_search_map() {

                                    var vals;
                                    vals = jQuery('#fe_map0 #loc_address').val();
                                    jQuery('#fe_map0 .gllpSearchField_fe').val(vals);
                                }

                                (function ($) {
                                    $(function () {
                                                    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('loc_address'));
                                                });
                                })(jQuery);
                                jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                                    var $ = jQuery;
                                    jQuery("[id^=map_canvas]").css("pointer-events", "none");
                                    jQuery("[id^=cs-map-location]").css("pointer-events", "none");
                                    // on leave handle
                                    var onMapMouseleaveHandler = function (event) {
                                        var that = jQuery(this);
                                        that.on('click', onMapClickHandler);
                                        that.off('mouseleave', onMapMouseleaveHandler);
                                        jQuery("[id^=map_canvas]").css("pointer-events", "none");
                                        jQuery("[id^=cs-map-location]").css("pointer-events", "none");
                                    }
                                    // on click handle
                                    var onMapClickHandler = function (event) {
                                        var that = jQuery(this);
                                        // Disable the click handler until the user leaves the map area
                                        that.off('click', onMapClickHandler);
                                        // Enable scrolling zoom
                                        that.find('[id^=map_canvas]').css("pointer-events", "auto");
                                        that.find('[id^=cs-map-location]').css("pointer-events", "auto");

                                        // Handle the mouse leave event
                                        that.on('mouseleave', onMapMouseleaveHandler);
                                    }
                                    // Enable map zooming with mouse scroll when the user clicks the map
                                    jQuery('.cs-map-section').on('click', onMapClickHandler);
                                    // new addition
                                });
```

Any help on implementing something is greatly appreciated, as I'm really struggling on this one! :D

Comment: Your functions are written in vastly different styles, which leads me to the conclusion that you copy-pasted all of them and wrote none of them yourself. Which would imply that you are looking for another piece of code that you can copy and paste. That's not a sustainable style of developing anything, really.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, this code isn't mine but through a theme that I purchased :/

Comment: Your first step should be to read the entire documentation of the Places Autocomplete API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete. It contains all the info you need to confine the suggestions to a certain area and much more.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, appreciate the guidance. Out of genuine interest, can you elaborate slightly on the different styles in the script above?

Comment: Well, there are four top level "blocks" in this piece of code. 1 and 4 share the same approach of using jQuery, 2 and 3 are different from 1 and 4 and different from each other. 4 is heavily commented, 1 is not, therefore all 4 functions have been written by different people at different times and probably in different projects, and all four have been copypasted and banged on until it sort-of worked.

Comment: Ok interesting to read, the theme as a whole has been buggy to say the least. It was my first purchase on themeforest - probably won't go down that route again anytime soon!

Comment: So what you need to do is modify the line `new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(...);` and add the options you want your autocomplete field to have. The API documentation lists them all. Calling `setComponentRestrictions` is another way of defining additional rules.

Comment: Thank you Tomalak your time is much appreciated.

Comment: I have no API key to test it with, so it's a difficult to provide code.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, sorry I have been off the grid, I can send you an API key if you can still help me with this? Still struggling to implement..  o_O Thank you

Comment: Hm, I gave you a pretty strong lead on where to start looking. I can't do "interactive debugging" via comments and I can't write it for you. My recommendation is to set up a [mcve] that contains none of your current code (!) but a from-scratch autocomplete field. Use StackOverflow's code snippets or a website like https://jsfiddle.net/ for that. Copy a sample from the documentation, there are plenty of complete samples there. Make changes to the sample. Add options to the line that builds the Autocomplete. See how it reacts. I would do exactly the same thing myself.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: In fact, your chances for an answer here are very good if you set up a new question with a working, interactive sample (I suppose you can set up a temporary API key just for the purpose to avoid leaking your real one). But the necessary modifications are lined out in the docs, you just have to pick them out. Take it as a challenge.

Comment: A challenge I am certainly finding it ! :D Thanks Tomalak, stay classy.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, I know you probably don't care but I have now solved my issue. Thank you for your time and assistance it's been really appreciated.

Comment: I do care, glad to hear you've sorted it out. And rather quickly, too! :) The proper thing to do would be to write down the thing you did in an answer below (I'll upvote, too) so other people might benefit from it some time.